# Rest assured with Testng - Error coming in delete request

Tags: java, arrays, json, rest, m2eclipse

[image]

**"contacts": [
"Expected a list of items but got type "int"."**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the error it looks like the expected PUT body needs to be an array say `{"contacts":[12,123]}`.  What you are giving is `{"contacts":12}`
There are 2 options:

1. Put the integer in an array. ie. request.put("contacts",[contact])
2. since your delete request already handles multiple ids, why use dataprovider, simply send the array in one go in contacts.